# Can any one have the link to compose the api from scratch in bluemix api connect?

Tags: api, wsdl, ibm-cloud, apiconnect

I have imported one api with wsdl file using the SOAP operation of API connect(Bluemix), for the same endpoint i want to compose the api from scratch without using the wsdl. I'm facing some issues when i'm doing it without wsdl

Comment: Does this "Creating APIs" link in the API Connect documentation help you?: https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/apiconnect/apic_003.html#apic_003

Comment: this is one is for the api designer local set up, I want to create it in the bluemix api connect.I'm not using local tool kit and designer for creating API's.

Answer (score 0):

There is a great tutorial provided in developerWorks that will show you how to use APIConnect on Bluemix to create, configure and publish APIs. I would recommend following along to gain the experience you are looking for:

[API Connect Tutorial: Mastering the API Assembly](https://developer.ibm.com/apiconnect/2016/11/21/api-connect-tutorial-mastering-the-api-assembly/)